# Отправка PDF на email (django)

Tags: python, django, email, pdf

Не получается сгенерировать pdf и отправить его приложением на email.

```
def send_email_info(request, *args, **kwargs):
        address = f"{response.data['profile']}."
        context = {
             "org_address": address,
        }
        pdf = render_to_pdf(context).getvalue()
        subject = "Welcom!"
        email_msg = EmailMessage(subject, body=pdf, from_email='cabinet@becloud.by', to=['qwerty@gmail.com'])
        email_msg.attach('address.pdf', pdf, "application/pdf")
        email_msg.content_subtype = "pdf"  
        email_msg.encoding = 'UTF-8'
        email_msg.send()
```

и функция, которая отвечает за рендер pdf

```
def render_to_pdf(context):
    html = render_to_string('cabinet/registration_data.html', context)
    result = BytesIO()
    pdf = pisa.pisaDocument(BytesIO(html.encode("UTF-8")), result, encoding='utf-8', link_callback=fetch_pdf_resources)
    if not pdf.err:
        return result
    else:
        return None
```

Ошибка не возникает, но и письмо не приходит. SMTP настроен правильно, потому что письма без из другой функции PDF приходят. Не понимаю, как исправить ситуацию.

Comment: сгенеренный пдф в базе не сохраняете?

Comment: не, не сохраняю. лучше сохранить было бы?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20717496/how-to-send-pdf-as-an-email-attachment-in-django

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49230593/10898133

Comment: И вот ещё одна последняя функция в джанго. Можете её попробовать https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/email/#sending-alternative-content-types

Comment: ок, спс, если получится, то выложу рабочий вариант

Comment: Не все почтовые сервера любят письма без текстового тела, положи в боди текст в хтмл или сырой